# How do I delete my Gmail account?

Tags: gmail, account-management, delete

I've got an old GMail account I hardly use and want to delete it. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out [this page](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=8152) on mail.google.com

1. Click Settings at the top of any Gmail page, and open the Accounts and Import tab.
2. Click Google Account settings.
3. Click Edit next to My products on the right side.
4. Click Remove Gmail permanently.